# What terms can I use for a shape close to a circle but shaped like amoeba?

Tags: geometry, terminology, circles, recreational-mathematics

What can I call measurements of circle which is not perfect and shaped like amoeba? Since it's not a circle I can't call it's measurements diameter, radius etc. [image]
[enter link description here](https://www.google.com/search?q=irregular%20circle%20shape&client=ms-android-micromax&prmd=isnv&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwip6b6mkZXxAhUCxjgGHYRpD0wQ_AUoAXoECAIQAQ&biw=360&bih=610&dpr=2#imgrc=hLuPMXtaBcF0EM)

Comment: If it is not a circle, it has no diameter.

Comment: Could you define a diameter as the longest internal chord?

Comment: If it's an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse), there are the semi-major and semi-minor axes.

Comment: @PeterPhipps it's not an ellipse, it's closed to circle but has irregular shape like an amoeba. Is there any way I can post a picture here to give an idea? As it is not a circle so I cannot call it's measurements dia, perimeter or radius. I was looking for proper terminology to describe it's measurements

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA  it's not an ellipse, it's closed to circle but has irregular shape like an amoeba. Is there any way I can post a picture here to give an idea? As it is not a circle so I cannot call it's measurements dia, perimeter or radius. I was looking for proper terminology to describe it's measurements

Comment: Arbitrary sets have diameters, usually defined as $\sup \{\|x-y\| \mid x,y \in E \}$ where $E$ is your set and you will need to replace the norm with whatever you are using for measurements.  If you need something fuzzier, "near-diameter" might suffice providing you define it properly to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can identify a center point (the center of mass, for instance) and then say that a segment from the perimeter is a radius. In a circle all the radiuses have the same length, but that is not usually the case for an amoeba. It will have a range of radiuses, and a minimum and maximum radius. You can do the same for diameters.

If you don't want to identify a center point, you can consider the "width" of the amoeba in a particular direction. Take two parallel lines and ask how close together they can be with the amoeba still able to fit in between. That is the width of the amoeba in the direction perpendicular to the lines. A circle has constant width, but an amoeba may not.

Answer (score 0):

The standard definition of diameter is the maximum distance between any two points, and of radius is $\min\limits_c\max\limits_rd(c,r)$.

For circles, these coincide with the obvious definitions.